# Camel consumer consuming file again and again from the FTP Root

Tags: apache-camel

Camel consuming the same file again and again from FTP Root. I have set `idempotent=true`.

If I put the file in FTP root folder/file1.txt, file consumed again and again

If I put the file in FTP root/some_directory/file1.txt, the file consumed only single time.

What is the problem?.

Comment: show us your route

Comment: from("ftp://ftpuser@172.26.17.96:21//?password=******&passiveMode=true&recursive=true&binary=true&idempotent=true").

to("file:src/main/resources/orderxmlroute/")

Answer (score 0):

I had same case I simply put `noop=true` and it's gone!